# I am Using MediaStore.Video to fetch Videos on phone but it displays only 3gp and MP4 Video

Tags: java, android, video, mediastore

I want to create a Video Player App, so I have to fetch and display Videos from phone on my App. I used MediaStore.Video in fetching Videos but I noticed only 3gp and MP4 Video extension format are fetched, how do I fetch all Videos extension from phone(all Video Formats) this is the code I used before

````
        Uri uri=MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; 
        String orderBy=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED; 
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA  , MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};

Cursor cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,orderBy); 
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToNext()){ 
            do{ 

                String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID));  
                String title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE));  
                String displayName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));  
                String size=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.SIZE));  
                String duration=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION));  
                String path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA));  
                String dateAdded=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED));  
                String video_thumb=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));  
                
                MediaFiles mediaFiles=new MediaFiles(video_thumb, id,title,duration,size,dateAdded,displayName,path);   
                videoFiles.add(mediaFiles); 
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());```

Please is there no way I can fetch all types of Videos using this code. Anyone help with any other way to fetch all types of Videos
````

Comment: Are there videos that are missing? Perhaps your phone only happens to have videos of those two types indexed in the `MediaStore`.

Comment: Nop I have other Videos with the format Avi, mpeg and webm, I have test app on other phone same issue,